# Why do i get this big gap between my content

Tags: html, css

i have these 6 columns which are float to left so they will appear next to each other but as you can see  the Demo once i increase the height of the middle content the 4 and 6 also pushes down but i want to keep same margin

CSS

```
.left-side-bar{
    clear: both;
    height: 200px;
    width: 32.26%;
    background-color: gray;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

.middle-side-bar{
    height: 340px;
    width: 32.26%;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.right-side-bar{
    height: 200px;
    width: 32.26%;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;    
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
```

these content can have different height . this was just for the question and i might have more than 6 columns

correct fiddle 
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cybersix/1000s8y0/18/)

Comment: What six columns are you talking about? the fiddle provided does not match your description

Comment: i think he is asking about masonry

Comment: http://sickdesigner.com/masonry-css-getting-awesome-with-css3/ it will help if you are looking for masonry css

Comment: do you want the other boxes to also become the same height? You'll need a wrapper div and position:absolute order some JS.

Comment: they will have different sizes something like this website http://demos.churchthemes.com/resurrect/

Comment: Try flex way. ((display: flex; with other settings)) search CSS FLEX keywords, You will find many documents. it must be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make three different columns in the container. You're thinking in horizontal lines, which is basic, but you should think vertically first. Basically it comes down to having 3 columns, and then in those columns divs with different heights.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-side-bar red">
        Column 1
    </div>

    <div class='middle-side-bar red'>
        Column 2
    </div>

    <div class='right-side-bar red'>
        Column 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cz099s1s/) for an example.

Comment: how to do i add margin between the columns ?

Comment: Something like this (edited) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cz099s1s/1/)?
Adding `margin-bottom` to the elements is the neatest.